# Magento 2.3.X to 2.4.X Readiness cron check non writable paths that don't exist

Tags: magento2, readiness-check

Im having the same problem with the readiness checkup on magento 2.3.5p1 with php 7.3 (can be changed easily if needed on both CLI and webserver).
It gives me a filepath for a subdirectory that doesnt exist For ex: x/public_html/Magento/app/etc/design/frontend/magento

When the documentroot is on the public_html not in the magento folder, this is not defined anywhere so i have no idea where its coming from. Creating the folder manually also doesnt work, permission are correct for other folders, but for some reason it keeps throwing this error

Answer (score 0):

After the Magento update, you also need to reinstall the cronjob.
Remove Magento 2.3 crons by bin/magento cron:remove or by deleting them from crontab and run bin/magento cron:install afterwards.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html